# How to add a new recurring contribution from the administrative side?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

I feel like it used to be possible for an administrator to add a new recurring donation from the administrative interface, but I can't find it in the **Contributions > New Contribution** or **Submit credit card contribution** screens at all.

Am I imagining that it used to be there or am I just missing it?

Comment: Which payment processor are you using?

Comment: Stripe (and recurring is showing on the front end contribution forms).

Comment: Okay updated my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it depends upon the payment processor you using to take offline payments. Some payment processors may not allow that.

For stripe you need to have billing address field enabled to show up(Should have setting available under Administer >> CiviContribute >> Stripe settings), by default the option is checked to disable to the billing address.

Comment: Thanks! I filed an issue here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/333

Answer (score 1):

I used it with Stripe Pro Payments and at the time, we had some trouble on the user side. I know that I added several recurring payments either from the admin side or I may have been altering the database entry.

If there is no ability through the admin interface, I would make a payment on your own account and look over its entry in the database.

My guess is (this was years ago) there will be a payment type one time|recurring or some variation of that. Try toggling that and see what happens.

PS back up the table (or database) before you make changes.

Karl